# How to generate rolling subsequences into a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

| col0 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| ... |
| 1000 |

I'd like roll col0 into a data frame with a window size of 5, so the outcome would be like this:

| col0 | col1 | col2 | ... | col995 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 996 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | 997 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | ... | 998 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | ... | 999 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | ... | 1000 |

I've tried using loops and "iloc" which would produce correct results, but as the original data frame gets much longer, it would take too long to finish.  To complete 10,000, it'd take almost 2 minutes, 20,000 almost 10 minutes, and so on...  Is there any way to do it faster, more efficiently in Python?

Comment: Unsure what "roll a column into a dataframe means". Can you provide an input along with the desired output and code?

Comment: well what about something like  `df[f'col{i}'] = df[f'col0'][i:i+5]` in a loop? Alternatively, you can create a dict and then convert it to a dataframe. Note that creating/manipulating dataframes with about thousands of columns is generally not very efficient (Pandas is not made for fast manipulation of wide dataframes). A loop of 1000 iterations is relatively fast in Python.

Comment: mozway just had the perfect answer below.  My choice of words wasn't the best.  It was supposed to be 'sliding window' as per mozway's solution.

Answer (score 17):

Use [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) and [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) (`T`):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

out = pd.DataFrame(swv(df['col0'], 5).T).add_prefix('col')
```

Output:

```
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  ...  col986  \
0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10  ...     987   
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11  ...     988   
2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12  ...     989   
3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13  ...     990   
4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14  ...     991   

   col987  col988  col989  col990  col991  col992  col993  col994  col995  
0     988     989     990     991     992     993     994     995     996  
1     989     990     991     992     993     994     995     996     997  
2     990     991     992     993     994     995     996     997     998  
3     991     992     993     994     995     996     997     998     999  
4     992     993     994     995     996     997     998     999    1000  

[5 rows x 996 columns]
```

Reproducible input:

```
N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': range(1, N+1)})
```

Timing for 100k rows:

```
25 ms ± 402 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @ntintel yes, I added a timing for 100k rows, about 25ms on my computer ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) for this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col0': range(1,1001)})

data = sliding_window_view(df['Col0'], 5).T

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                      columns=[f'Col{i}' for i in range(data.shape[1])])

print(df_new)

   Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  ...  Col991  Col992  Col993  Col994  Col995
0     1     2     3     4     5  ...     992     993     994     995     996
1     2     3     4     5     6  ...     993     994     995     996     997
2     3     4     5     6     7  ...     994     995     996     997     998
3     4     5     6     7     8  ...     995     996     997     998     999
4     5     6     7     8     9  ...     996     997     998     999    1000

[5 rows x 996 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solution is awesome.  Same as mozway's above.